# Asymptotics for the sums from the inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, inclusion-exclusion

What is a method to compute the asymptotics of a sum resulting from the inclusion-exclusion principle? Each term of the sum can be approximated perhaps by Sterling's formula or the Gaussian distribution. However the alternating sign should effect some cancellation. As an example, the [answer to this combinatorial problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3172541/64809) generates a probability
$$p=\frac c{n\choose j},$$
where
$$c=\sum_{k=w}^j(-1)^{k-w}(j-k+1){n-k+1\choose j-k+1}.$$
What is the asymptote of $p$ for $\big|\frac jn-a\big|=o(n)$ and $\big|\frac wn-b\big|=o(n)$ for some positive numbers $a$ and $b$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? Of course, the summands have alternating signs and the absolute values of which decreases, so we can always bound the sum with partial sums. But I am hoping for a neater expression for asymptotics and a general tool for producing it.

Comment: cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327293/asymptotics-for-the-sums-from-the-inclusion-exclusion-principle